# « Et cetera » est-il prononcé de la même manière en français qu'en anglais?

Tags: prononciation, latin

Je suis tombé sur l'expression latine « et cetera » dans un texte français, et je me suis demandé si je devrais le prononcer de la même manière qu'en anglais.

Est-ce le cas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Les prononciations en français de France ( /ɛt.se.te.ʁa/ ) et en anglais ( /ɛt ˈsɛt.ə.ɹə/ ) sont très similaires en effet.

Il convient de noter qu'au Québec, *et cetera* est prononcé de manière sensiblement différente ( ɛt ʃe.te.ʁɑ/ ). De plus, il n'est pas rare d'entendre en France prononcer /ɛk se.te.ʁa/ .

Pour des exemples de prononciations, et la décomposition en phonèmes, on pourra se référer à l'article du [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_cetera)

Answer (score 3):

Merci à @Alexis pour l'explication très intéressante et, je crois, complète.

La seule chose que je voudrais ajouter est que l'accent de cette expression tombe sur la dernière syllabe en Français (comme s'il était "et ceter **à** "), tandis qu'en Anglais l'accent est sur la deuxième syllabe ("et  c **é** tera").